# Error when using fast_executemany = True in sql alchemy with driver='SQL+Server'

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use fast_executemany to speed up my df.to_sql insert.
I read the documentation and added it to my code like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
import numpy as np
import random

#connect to database
server = 'Test'
database = 'Test'
driver = 'SQL+Server'
driver1 = 'ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'
engine_stmt = ("mssql+pyodbc://@%s/%s?driver=%s" % (server, database, driver))

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_stmt, fast_executemany=True)
connection = engine.connect()
```

When I run this code without the `fast_executemany` it works, but it takes fairly long for the insert.
Therefore I wanted to use the command, but I get an error when using it with the `'SQL+Server'` driver. Therefore I tried to change the driver according to the documentation to `'ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'` I get the following error:

```
def create_connect_args(self, url):

InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

So I guess this driver is not working for me? I tested a few different ones, but the only one that is working is the `'SQL+Server'`

Comment: Did you install that ODBC driver?  Only the legacy "SQL Server" driver part of Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I checked it in the administrative tools and I have ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server, so I guess it should work using driver1 from my code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the [ODBC 13 driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50420) on your computer.
Try installing that and run your script again.

Alternatively, try swapping:

```
driver1 = 'ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server'
```

for

```
driver1 = 'ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
```